# Why is Github always including my API keys in Release Source Code?

Tags: git, api, github

I pushed my code on Github accidentally pushing my Github API Keys also. And I then created a release, which included my API Key. I immediately removed the API keys from the source code and also deleted the release. I then created a release which by default should not have my API Keys (I deleted it in my main source code and then created the release). But every time I create a new release, my API key is always present in the release source code even if I deleted the keys from my main file.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I fixed it.

I created a release with a new tag and then I deleted the previous tag.

Comment: If so, please mark your question as solved. Maybe you want to add some additional information for future readers.